# JavaScript Get Current Time & Countdown

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm using JavaScript to get the Current Time, and I want it to countdown every 2 hours starting at 12am est.

I currently have code that counts down 2 hours and resets, but I want it to do it based off the time from 12am.

I either want to get my current code to start at 12am rather than when some accesses the page or I need to do it some other way (open to suggestions).

Thanks a lot!

```
var startTime = new Date(),
    expiryTime = new Date(),
    hourElem = document.getElementById('js-hour'),
    minuteElem = document.getElementById('js-minute'),
    secondElem = document.getElementById('js-second');

// Set up expiry time
expiryTime.setHours( expiryTime.getHours() + 2 );
expiryTime.setMinutes( expiryTime.getMinutes() + 0 );
expiryTime.setSeconds( expiryTime.getSeconds() + 0 );

var diffInMs = expiryTime - startTime,
    diffInSecs = Math.round( diffInMs / 1000 ),
    amountOfHours = Math.floor( diffInSecs / 3600 ),
    amountOfSeconds = diffInSecs - (amountOfHours * 3600),
    amountOfMinutes = Math.floor( amountOfSeconds / 60 ),
    amountOfSeconds = amountOfSeconds - ( amountOfMinutes * 60 );

// Set up the countdown timer for display
// Set up the hours
if( amountOfHours > 0 ) {
  hourElem.innerHTML = (amountOfHours < 10)
  ? '0' + amountOfHours + ' : '
  : amountOfHours + ' : ';
} else {
  hourElem.innerHTML = '00 : ';
}

// Set up the minutes
if( amountOfMinutes > 0 ) {
  minuteElem.innerHTML = ( amountOfMinutes < 10 )
  ? '0' + amountOfMinutes + ' : '
  : amountOfMinutes + ' : ';
} else {
  minuteElem.innerHTML = '00 : ';
}

// // Set up the seconds
if( amountOfSeconds > 0 ) {
  secondElem.innerHTML = (amountOfSeconds < 10)
  ? '0' + amountOfSeconds
  : amountOfSeconds;
} else {
  secondElem.innerHTML = '00';
}

function countDown() {
  var dateNow = new Date();

  // If we're not at the end of the timer, continue the countdown
  if( expiryTime > dateNow ) {

  // References to current countdown values
  var hours = parseInt(hourElem.innerHTML);
      minutes = parseInt(minuteElem.innerHTML),
      seconds = parseInt(secondElem.innerHTML);

  // Update the hour if necessary
  if( minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
    if (  hours != 0) {
    --hours;

    hourElem.innerHTML = ( hours < 10 ) ? '0' + (hours) + ' : ' : (hours) + ' : ';
    minuteElem.innerHTML = '59 : ';
    secondElem.innerHTML = '59';
    return;
    }
    else {
        hourElem.innerHTML = '02 : ';
        minuteElem.innerHTML = '00 : ';
    secondElem.innerHTML = '00';
    return;
    }

  }

  // Update the minute if necessary
  if( seconds == 0 ) {

    if( minutes > 0 ) {
      --minutes;
      minuteElem.innerHTML = ( minutes > 10 ) ? minutes + ' : ' : '0' + minutes + ' : ';

      } else {
        minuteElem.innerHTML = '59' + ' : ';
      }

      return secondElem.innerHTML = '59';

    } else {
      --seconds;
      secondElem.innerHTML = ( seconds < 10 ) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    }

  } else {
 expiryTime.setHours( expiryTime.getHours() + 2 );
expiryTime.setMinutes( expiryTime.getMinutes() + 0 );
expiryTime.setSeconds( expiryTime.getSeconds() + 0 );



  }
}


window.onload = function() {
  // Begin the countdown!
  countDownInterval = setInterval( countDown, 1000 );
}
```

Comment: What if nobody is on your page at 12am???

Comment: If you have a 2 hour countdown then it counts from 12 AM to 2AM and resets. At 4AM, 6AM, 8AM, 10AM, 12PM etc it resets. If the time is 5AM the time should be at one hour counting down to 0. So what it sounds like is you need to adjust how you seed your timer. Your timer seed is always set to 2 and that is not always true.

Comment: We have a service that resets at 12am and every 2 hours after that. Basically I need to replicate that for the website in javascript. I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment you need to change how you seed the timer.

Right now you are setting the time to expire to be 2 hours from the current system time instead of a 2 hour rotating timer.

If you calculated the number of seconds from Midnight of the current date then you'd know where to start the seed.

There are 7200 seconds in 2 hours. If you take the number of seconds from Midnight and use MOD to determine the remainder you'd be determining how far into the 2 hour block you are. Then use 7200 minus the remainder.

From there you can calculate the number of hours, minutes and seconds that are remaining until the countdown expires.

(*Starting to sound like homework so I won't post any code)

Comment: Alright, thanks, I'll try to do something with that.It's a project for work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out my issue. I forgot that Date.now() gives the date since 12am on some day. I took that in ms, transferred it to seconds, took the MOD of that % 7200 and subtracted 7200 from that to get it to count down. Then I just did some rounding and simple subtraction to get hours minutes and seconds.

```
    var end = Date.now();
var div = (end / 1000);
var time = (div / 7200);
var timesince = (div % 7200);
var timebefore = (7200 - timesince);

var hours = Math.floor(timebefore / 3600);
var minutes = Math.floor(timebefore / 60 - hours * 60);
var seconds = Math.floor(timebefore - minutes * 60 - hours * 3600);

document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```